# Class cannot be stored

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been developing a BPMN editor and the task can be modified based on context menu. I used [this](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html) to implement it.

So, whenever the user changes the task type, a class will be called. But I am having a hard time trying to figure out to save the class. Cause whenever the user changes the selected item, the "current" item is the one that will change and the class from before will be removed. I saved the class name but I cannot retrieve. I am now stuck. Thank you for your help.

These is what I've tried so far:

```
menu_shape= function(){
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.activity',
        trigger: 'left',
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var m = key;
            menu_shape_action(key);
        },
        items: {

            "fold1":{
                "name": "Set Task Type", 
                "items": {
                    "default":{"name": "Default"},
                    "business_rule":{"name": "Business Rule"},
                    "manual":{"name": "Manual"},
                    "receive":{"name": "Receive"},
                     "send":{"name": "Send"},
                     "script":{"name": "Script"},
                     "service":{"name": "Service"},
                     "user":{"name": "User"},
                }
            },
            "fold1a": {
                "name": "Convert to", 
                "items": {
                    "task":{"name": "Task"},
                    "sub_process":  {"name": "Sub-process"},
                     "global_task":  {"name": "Global Task"},
                      "global_process":  {"name": "Global Process"}
                }
            }
        }
    });


}

 var ctr= null; var task_type=null; 
 menu_shape_action = function(action){

if( ctr){
         task_type.removeClass(ctr);
    }  

switch(action){
            case "default":
                $(current).addClass("default");
                ctr= "default";
            break;

            case "business_rule":
                task_type = $(current).addClass("business_rule");
                ctr= "business_rule";
            break;

            case "manual":
                task_type = $(current).addClass("manual");
                ctr= "manual";
            break;

            case "receive":
                task_type = $(current).addClass("receive");
                ctr= "receive";
            break;

            case "send":
                task_type = $(current).addClass("send");
                ctr= "send";
            break;

            case "script":
                task_type = $(current).addClass("script");
                ctr= "script";
            break;

            case "service":
                task_type = $(current).addClass("service");
                ctr= "service";
            break;

            case "user":
                task_type = $(current).addClass("user");
                ctr= "user";
            break;

            default:
              $(current).addClass("default");
              ctr= "default";
            break; 

}

t_type =task_type.attr("ctr",ctr);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your current example you can access the stored data by doing `task_type.attr("ctr")` but really you should be using the jQuery method [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).